# How do I make setState run synchronously in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I need to load in a JSON file of 26731 elements, then get the length and then generate a random element and use the values in the code. But this async Reactjs drives me nuts and I spend forever trying to get simple things to sync

The problem is that although I can load up the JSON to dictionary:[] I can't use it to generate the length of the random number.

I tried the Spread Operator ...this.state but it didn't seem appropriate and didn't make a difference.

My State

```
this.state = {
  dictionary: [],
  isLoaded: false,
  dictLength: 0,
  rnd: 0
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadUpDictionary();
  this.DictionaryLength();
  this.RandomNumber();
}
```

This works because I can see a dictionary in the Render. The code is OK, except componentDidMount does not run the functions in order.

```
loadUpDictionary() {
  loadDictionary().then(d => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      dictionary: d,
      isLoaded: true
    }));
    //  console.log(this.state.dictionary);
  });
}
```

But these functions don't hold any value because before it renders dictionary doesn't hold any value

```
DictionaryLength() {
  const Length = this.state.dictionary.length;
   console.log("Length of dictionary " + Length); //outputs Length of dictionary 0
  this.setState(() => ({
    dictLength: Length
  }));
}

RandomNumber() {
const min = 0;
const max = this.state.dictLength - 1;
const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
this.setState(() => ({
    rnd: rnd
  }));
}
```

Render

```
render() {
  const { isLoaded, dictionary, dictLength, rnd } = this.state; //pass across the state

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading ....</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          Dictionary loaded {dictionary.Entries.length} RND {rnd} dictLength{" "}
          {dictLength}
        </h1>
        <h2>Get a single entry {dictionary.Entries[3].Word} </h2> means{" "}
        {dictionary.Entries[3].Definition}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Output

Dictionary loaded 26731 RND 0 dictLength 0
Get a single entry Abaft
means naut. adv. In the stern half of a ship. prep. Nearer the stern than. [from *a2, -baft: see *aft]

For me, this is the hardest part of React...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with React, but is how JavaScript works

```js
this.loadUpDictionary();
this.DictionaryLength();
this.RandomNumber();

loadUpDictionary() {
loadDictionary().then(d => {
  this.setState(() => ({
    dictionary: d,
    isLoaded: true
  }));
  //  console.log(this.state.dictionary);
});
}
```

The moment `this.loadUpDictionary` being executed, `this.DictionaryLength()` will immediately get executed. You has a `.then` in `loadUpDictionary` but it will only be executed after `this.DictionaryLength` and `this.RandomNumber`. Hence quick fix

```js
loadUpDictionary() {
loadDictionary().then(d => {
  this.setState(() => ({
    dictionary: d,
    isLoaded: true
  }), () => {
    this.DictionaryLength();
  });
  //  console.log(this.state.dictionary);
});
}
```

The idea is that let the `this.loadUpDictionary` and `this.setState` run first, and since `setState` allows to have callback, you can have `this.DictionaryLength()` to do just that

Answer (score 3):

In general, unless there's a good reason, you don't want to be calling `setState` multiple times within a function, since that will degrade performance. You want to collate all your data, then call `setState` once with *all* the data. So, load the dictionary, calculate your random number, then call `setState` once, updating all 4 state values at the same time. Something like this (haven't tested this):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadUpDictionary()
    .then(d => {
      const min = 0;
      const max = d.length - 1;
      const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
      this.setState({
        dictionary: d,
        isLoaded: true
        dictLength: d.length,
        rnd
      });
    });
}

loadUpDictionary() {
  return loadDictionary();
}
```

The subsequent calls will be nested inside the loading `.then`, but that's fine since they're dependent on it anyway.

If you want to have calculation of the dictionary length and the random number in their own, synchronous functions you can still do that and call them, e.g.

```
.then(d => {
  this.setState({
     dictionary: d,
     isLoaded: true
     dictLength: this.DictionaryLength(d),
     rnd: this.RandomNumber(d)
  });
}
```

Just have those functions *return* the value, instead of setting it in state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how async works. The code will execute and continue to the next line **before** the previous function completes. So in your scenario, each function runs immediately, not waiting for the previous function to complete.

```
this.loadUpDictionary();
this.DictionaryLength();
this.RandomNumber();
```

This is why promises exist. Some options - depending on your target browsers, use a promise library like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) and return promises from your functions, or use javascript [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) so that your calls complete before you attempt to process the results in the next step.

However, looking at your code above, I would suggest combining the processing of the dictionary into a single function and set the state from there. I'd avoid loading the entire dictionary into the state unless needed. Something like:

```
initializeDictionary = async () => {
    // wait for the data to return
    const dictionary = await loadDictionary();

    const min = 0;
    const max = dictionary.Entries.length - 1;
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

    // get a random entry
    const entry = dictionary.Entries[rnd];

    // set the entry (length if needed)
    this.setState({
        entry: entry,
        dictionaryLength: dictionary.Entries.length
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Embrace asynchronous programming! Its benefit can be illustrated using a breakfast example. If you're making toast, would you rather do nothing after you start the toaster, or start the toaster, then get out the orange juice and cereal while you wait for the toast to be ready?

Same with async programming: you can fire off a HTTP request and keep interacting with the user until the data comes back instead of hanging the browser. If you need to make 20 independent HTTP requests, async allows you to make them all at once instead of doing them sequentially.

The code you've given seems pretty close to the sort of flow that will work, but the main issue appears to be this function:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadUpDictionary();
  this.DictionaryLength(); // depends on `this.loadUpDictionary` resolving
  this.RandomNumber();     // also depends on `this.loadUpDictionary` resolving
}
```

If `this.loadUpDictionary()` is asynchronous, then this pattern above has a race condition and your data can't be guaranteed to be ready by the time you're trying to use it. A solution is to chain `then` or `await` the results of the asynchronous call which guarantees that the promise has resolved. This is like waiting to put jam on your toast until after it's toasted -- a real dependency.

Having said this, there's really no need to store the length of `dictionary` in its own variable. You already have the `dictionary.length` property, so this is just more state to worry about keeping consistent.

Chances are, `isLoaded` is not necessary either. React automatically knows the load is done because of the state change and will trigger a re-render. Just make the HTTP request for the dictionary and pick a random word when the request resolves.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {dictionary: []};
  }
  
  async loadDictionary() {
    try {
      const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_dictionary.json"; // 6.51 MB
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      this.setState({dictionary: Object.keys(data)});    
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
  
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadDictionary();
  }

  render() {
    const {dictionary} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {dictionary.length
          ? <div>
              <p>Random word: {dictionary[~~(Math.random()*dictionary.length)]}</p> 
              <p>dictionary length: {dictionary.length}</p>
            </div>
          : <p>loading...</p>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

And here's a runnable snippet with hooks and a fake request that also picks the random word when the request arrives rather than at the time of the render:

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [dictionary, setDictionary] = useState([]);
  const [randomWord, setRandomWord] = useState("");
  
  const loadDictionary = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await new Promise(resolve => 
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000, {data: ["apples", "bananas", "cherries"]})
      );
      setDictionary(response.data);
      setRandomWord(response.data[~~(Math.random()*response.data.length)]);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadDictionary();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {dictionary.length
        ? <div>
            <p>Random word: {randomWord}</p> 
            <p>dictionary length: {dictionary.length}</p>
          </div>
        : <p>loading...</p>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Example />);

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```